# Angular 6 - Heroku reported "Build Succeeded", but no build is created

Tags: angular, heroku

I get an error page reporting: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/dist/index.html'` when deploying to Heroku after updating to Angular 6. Everything worked fine on Angular 5.

I can create the builds manually or on GitLab without issue, so I know the paths are fine. I can deploy to my local web server or to Azure, no hiccups. I am only having issues with the Heroku environment.

I have tried specifying exact versions of engines, but that resulted in no discernible change.

Here is the Heroku output during the build in question:

```
    Counting objects: 1, done.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 195 bytes | 195.00 KiB/s, done.                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
    remote: Compressing source files... done.
    remote: Building source:
    remote:
    remote: -----> Node.js app detected
    remote:
    remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
    remote:
    remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
    remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
    remote:        NODE_ENV=heroku
    remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
    remote:
    remote: -----> Installing binaries
    remote:        engines.node (package.json):  >=8.9.4
    remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   >=5.6.0
    remote:        engines.yarn (package.json):  >=1.5.1
    remote:
    remote:        Resolving node version >=8.9.4...
    remote:        Downloading and installing node 10.4.0...
    remote:        Bootstrapping npm >=5.6.0 (replacing 6.1.0)...
    remote:        npm 6.1.0 installed
    remote:        Resolving yarn version >=1.5.1...
    remote:        Downloading and installing yarn (1.7.0)...
    remote:        Installed yarn 1.7.0
    remote:
    remote: -----> Restoring cache
    remote:        Skipping cache restore (disabled)
    remote:
    remote: -----> Building dependencies
    remote:        Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
    remote:        yarn install v1.7.0
    remote:        [1/4] Resolving packages...
    remote:        [2/4] Fetching packages...
    remote:        (node:256) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
    remote:        info fsevents@1.2.4: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
    remote:        info "fsevents@1.2.4" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
    remote:        info fsevents@1.2.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
    remote:        info "fsevents@1.2.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
    remote:        [3/4] Linking dependencies...
    remote:        warning " > bootstrap@4.0.0-beta" has unmet peer dependency "jquery@>=3.0.0".
    remote:        warning " > bootstrap@4.0.0-beta" has unmet peer dependency "popper.js@^1.11.0".
    remote:        [4/4] Building fresh packages...
    remote:        Done in 55.06s.
    remote:
    remote: -----> Caching build
    remote:        Clearing previous node cache
    remote:        Skipping cache save (disabled by config)
    remote:
    remote: -----> Pruning devDependencies
    remote:        Skipping because NODE_ENV is not 'production'
    remote:
    remote: -----> Build succeeded!
    remote:  !     Unmet dependencies don't fail yarn install but may cause runtime issues
    remote:        https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7494
    remote:
    remote: -----> Discovering process types
    remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
    remote:
    remote: -----> Compressing...
    remote:        Done: 87.8M
    remote: -----> Launching...
    remote:        Released v62
    remote:        https://app-name.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
    remote:
    remote: Verifying deploy... done.
```

Here are my relevant project files:

- Procfile

  ```
  web: node server.js
  ```
- server.js

```js
    //Install express server

    const express = require('express');

    const http = require('http');

    const path = require('path');

    const app = express();

    // Serve only the static files from the dist directory

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {

    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));

    });

    const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

    app.set(port);

    const server = http.createServer(app);

    server.listen(port, () => console.log('Running…'));
```

- angular.json

```json
    {
      "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
      "version": 1,
      "newProjectRoot": "projects",
      "projects": {
        "app": {
          "root": "",
          "sourceRoot": "src",
          "projectType": "application",
          "architect": {
            "build": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
              "options": {
                "outputPath": "dist",
                "index": "src/index.html",
                "main": "src/main.ts",
                "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.json",
                "assets": [
                  "src/assets",
                  "src/favicon.ico"
                ],
                "styles": [
                  "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
                  "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
                  "src/styles.scss"
                ],
                "scripts": [
                  "node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js",
                  "node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"
                ]
              },
              "configurations": {
                "dev": {
                  "fileReplacements": [
                    {
                      "replace": "src/./environments/environment.ts",
                      "with": "src/./environments/environment.dev.ts"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "reader": {
                  "optimization": true,
                  "outputHashing": "all",
                  "sourceMap": false,
                  "extractCss": true,
                  "namedChunks": false,
                  "aot": true,
                  "extractLicenses": true,
                  "vendorChunk": false,
                  "buildOptimizer": true,
                  "fileReplacements": [
                    {
                      "replace": "src/./environments/environment.ts",
                      "with": "src/./environments/environment.reader.ts"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "heroku": {
                  "optimization": true,
                  "outputHashing": "all",
                  "sourceMap": false,
                  "extractCss": true,
                  "namedChunks": false,
                  "aot": true,
                  "extractLicenses": true,
                  "vendorChunk": false,
                  "buildOptimizer": true,
                  "fileReplacements": [
                    {
                      "replace": "src/./environments/environment.ts",
                      "with": "src/./environments/environment.heroku.ts"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "staging": {
                  "optimization": true,
                  "outputHashing": "all",
                  "sourceMap": false,
                  "extractCss": true,
                  "namedChunks": false,
                  "aot": true,
                  "extractLicenses": true,
                  "vendorChunk": false,
                  "buildOptimizer": true,
                  "fileReplacements": [
                    {
                      "replace": "src/./environments/environment.ts",
                      "with": "src/./environments/environment.staging.ts"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "production": {
                  "optimization": true,
                  "outputHashing": "all",
                  "sourceMap": false,
                  "extractCss": true,
                  "namedChunks": false,
                  "aot": true,
                  "extractLicenses": true,
                  "vendorChunk": false,
                  "buildOptimizer": true,
                  "fileReplacements": [
                    {
                      "replace": "src/./environments/environment.ts",
                      "with": "src/./environments/environment.prod.ts"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "serve": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
              "options": {
                "browserTarget": "app:build"
              },
              "configurations": {
                "dev": {
                  "browserTarget": "app:build:dev"
                },
                "reader": {
                  "browserTarget": "app:build:reader"
                },
                "heroku": {
                  "browserTarget": "app:build:heroku"
                },
                "staging": {
                  "browserTarget": "app:build:staging"
                },
                "production": {
                  "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
                }
              }
            },
            "extract-i18n": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
              "options": {
                "browserTarget": "app:build"
              }
            },
            "test": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
              "options": {
                "main": "src/test.ts",
                "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
                "scripts": [
                  "node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js",
                  "node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"
                ],
                "styles": [
                  "node_modules/ng2-toastr/bundles/ng2-toastr.min.css",
                  "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
                  "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
                  "src/styles.scss"
                ],
                "assets": [
                  "src/assets",
                  "src/favicon.ico"
                ]
              }
            },
            "lint": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
              "options": {
                "tsConfig": [
                  "src/tsconfig.json"
                ],
                "exclude": []
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "app-e2e": {
          "root": "",
          "sourceRoot": "",
          "projectType": "application",
          "architect": {
            "e2e": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
              "options": {
                "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
                "devServerTarget": "app:serve"
              }
            },
            "lint": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
              "options": {
                "tsConfig": [
                  "e2e/tsconfig.json"
                ],
                "exclude": []
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "defaultProject": "app",
      "cli": {
        "warnings": {
          "typescriptMismatch": false
        }
      },
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:class": {
          "spec": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "spec": true,
          "inlineStyle": false,
          "inlineTemplate": false,
          "prefix": "app",
          "styleext": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "prefix": "app"
        }
      }
    }
```

- package.json

```json
{
    "name": "app",
    "version": "1.99.99",
    "angular-cli": {},
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "dangerzone": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0",
        "dev": "ng build --prod --configuration=dev",
        "heroku": "ng build --prod --configuration=heroku",
        "prod": "ng build --prod",
        "reader": "ng build --prod --configuration=reader",
        "staging": "ng build --prod --configuration=staging",
        "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" --project src/tsconfig.json && tslint \"e2e/**/*.ts\" --project e2e/tsconfig.json",
        "lint:fix": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\" --project src/tsconfig.json --fix && tslint \"e2e/**/*.ts\" --project e2e/tsconfig.json --fix",
        "test": "ng test",
        "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
        "e2e": "protractor"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=8.9.4",
        "npm": ">=5.6.0",
        "yarn": ">=1.5.1"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "0.7.0-beta.1",
        "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/cdk": "^6.2.0",
        "@angular/cli": "^6.0.7",
        "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/material": "^6.2.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/platform-server": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
        "angular-tree-component": "^7.0.1",
        "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta",
        "core-js": "^2.5.7",
        "d3": "^4.10.0",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "moment": "^2.19.3",
        "ng2-idle-core": "^6.0.1",
        "ng2-split-pane": "^1.4.0",
        "ngx-color-picker": "^6.1.0",
        "ngx-cookie": "^3.0.1",
        "rxjs": "^6.1.0",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.1.0",
        "typescript": "2.7.2",
        "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0-beta.1",
        "@types/d3": "^4.10.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.54",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.95",
        "@types/node": "10.1.4",
        "codelyzer": "^4.3.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
        "jasmine": "^3.1.0",
        "jasmine-core": "^3.1.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
        "karma": "^2.0.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
        "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.1.0",
        "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
        "protractor": "^5.1.2",
        "ts-node": "^6.0.3",
        "tslint": "^5.10.0",
        "use-yarn": "^2.2.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you run the build of the angular app in production mode before deploy the git repository on Heroku? If I'm not wrong, I don't see in your package.json any "postinstall" settings.

Comment: You're right, I had removed `postinstall` during the upgrade and forgot to add it back in. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had removed the `postinstall` script during the upgrade and neglected to add it again afterwards. Here is the amended package.json section pointing to this project's custom postinstall script:

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "postinstall": "node scripts/postinstall.js"
  },
  ...
}
```